# Warning message in scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, xor

I wrote a very simple scikit-learn decision tree to implement XOR:

```
from sklearn import tree
X = [[0, 0], [1, 1], [0, 1], [1, 0]]
Y = [0, 0, 1, 1]
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(X, Y)

print(clf.predict([0,1]))
print(clf.predict([0,0]))
print(clf.predict([1,1]))
print(clf.predict([1,0]))
```

predict part generates some warning like this:

> DeprecationWarning: Passing 1d arrays as data is deprecated in 0.17
> and will raise ValueError in 0.19. Reshape your data either using
> X.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or X.reshape(1, -1)
> if it contains a single sample.

What needs to change and why?

Comment: seems like the data you pass to predict should be in the same format as the data you pass to fit. use [[0,1]] instead of [0,1]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The input to `clf.predict` should be a 2D array. Thus, instead of writing

`print(clf.predict([0,1]))`

you need to write

`print(clf.predict([[0,1]]))`

Answer (score 0):

The method operates on matrices (2D arrays), rather than vectors (1D arrays).  As a convenience, the older code accepted a vector as a 1xN matrix.  This led to usage errors as some users forgot which way a vector was oriented (1xN vs Nx1).

The suggestion tells you how to reshape your vector to the proper matrix shape.  For constant vectors, just write them as matrices:

```
clf.predict( [ [0, 1] ] )
```

The "other direction" (wrong for this application) would be

```
clf.predict( [ [0], [1] ] )
```

Answer (score 0):

As the warning message pointed out, you have single sample to test. Thus you could use reshape or fix as followings,

```
from sklearn import tree
X = [[0, 0], [1, 1], [0, 1], [1, 0]]
Y = [0, 0, 1, 1]
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(X, Y)

print (clf.predict([[0,1]]))
print (clf.predict([[0,0]]))
print (clf.predict([[1,1]]))
print (clf.predict([[1,0]]))
```

Comment: What does this add, with respect to `Miriam Farber`'s answer?